# WPF: Is it possible to show one item on an ItemsControl more than once?

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I'd like to create a control, but I don't really know how to name it in english, that's why I don't really know what to google for either.

So, if there's already a name for it and/or if there's already a control with the following functionality out there, please let me know.

My control is some kind of an `ItemsControl`, but with one difference. If it contains too less items to fill the viewport completely, it should start with the first item again until the viewport is completely filled.

So, if the viewport has space for let's say five items, and my `ItemsSource` only contains two items, the control should show item 1, then 2, then 1, then 2 and then 1 again.

Think of it as the WPF equivalent of the news band on the bottom of TV news channels. It's circling through the available items and if it reaches the end it starts with the first item again, with no gap in between.

I already tried to create my own panel for this, but I couldn't find a way to show one item more than once in this panel. Is this even possible?

How would you create such a control? Can I base that on the default `ItemsControl` or do I have to inherit from `Control` and start from scratch?

Thank you for your thoughts and the push in the right direction.

---

Edit 1:

I tried the following to follow the suggestion in answer 1.

I created a `RecurringEnumerator(Of T)`:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class RecurringEnumerator(Of T)
    Implements IEnumerator(Of T)

    Private _internal As ICollection(Of T)
    Private _currentIndex As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal internal As ICollection(Of T))
        If (internal Is Nothing) Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("internal")
        End If

        _internal = internal
        _currentIndex = -1
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Current As T Implements IEnumerator(Of T).Current
        Get
            Return _internal(_currentIndex)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property CurrentObject As Object Implements IEnumerator.Current
        Get
            Return _internal(_currentIndex)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function MoveNext() As Boolean Implements IEnumerator.MoveNext
        If (_internal.Count = 0) Then
            Return False
        End If

        _currentIndex += 1

        If (_currentIndex >= _internal.Count) Then
            _currentIndex -= _internal.Count
        End If

        Return True
    End Function

    Public Sub Reset() Implements IEnumerator.Reset
        _currentIndex = -1
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    End Sub

End Class
```

And then I used this `RecurringEnumerator(Of T)` in a `RecurringCollection(Of T)`:
    Public Class RecurringCollection(Of T)
        Implements ICollection(Of T)

```
    Private _enumerator As RecurringEnumerator(Of T)
    Private _internal As ObjectModel.Collection(Of T)

    Public Sub New()
        _enumerator = New RecurringEnumerator(Of T)(Me)
        _internal = New ObjectModel.Collection(Of T)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of T) Implements IEnumerable(Of T).GetEnumerator
        Return _enumerator
    End Function

    Public Function GetObjectEnumerator() As IEnumerator Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
        Return _enumerator
    End Function

    Public Sub Add(ByVal item As T) Implements ICollection(Of T).Add
        _internal.Add(item)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Clear() Implements ICollection(Of T).Clear
        _internal.Clear()
    End Sub

    Public Function Contains(ByVal item As T) As Boolean Implements ICollection(Of T).Contains
        Return _internal.Contains(item)
    End Function

    Public Sub CopyTo(ByVal array() As T, ByVal arrayIndex As Integer) Implements ICollection(Of T).CopyTo
        _internal.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex)
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer Implements ICollection(Of T).Count
        Get
            Return _internal.Count
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReadOnly As Boolean Implements ICollection(Of T).IsReadOnly
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function Remove(ByVal item As T) As Boolean Implements ICollection(Of T).Remove
        Return _internal.Remove(item)
    End Function

End Class
```

But putting three short strings inside this `RecurringCollection(Of T)` and for-eaching through the collection and show a message box for each string resulted in a `StackOverflowException` without showing at least one message box.

I didn't create a custom collection before, so I'm not sure if I did everything right.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of trying to manipulate the `ItemsControl` you can create a specialized collection. I have written a template below. I have omitted error checking and the other `ICollection<T>` methods for the sake of brevity. You can easily delegate the methods to the internal list.

```
public class RecurringList<T> : ICollection<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> _items = new List<T>();

    public int DesiredCount { get; set; }
    public int Count => _items.Count > 0 ? DesiredCount : 0;

    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (_items.Count == 0)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        int count = Math.Max(DesiredCount, _items.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            yield return _items[i % _items.Count];
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _items.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return _items.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _items.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return _items.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter!

I tried your solution, but your code didn't work, for instance does your function `GetEnumerator` return values of Type T, but should return an `IEnumerator<T>`.
See my edit of the question for what I tried instead.

Comment: I have tried this solution and it worked well. The `GetEnumerator` function **yield** returns `T`. This is the `IEnumerable` pattern for C#. You can see an explanation [here](http://james-ramsden.com/implement-ienumerable-c/).

Comment: Then I'll try it again in C#.

Comment: Would you please paste the complete code of this class somewhere, I don't know what to return in the `Current` properties or what to do in the `MoveNext` function, since you seem to do everything in the `GetEnumerator` function.

Comment: I have added the full code. You don't need to create an `Enumerator` class. You should be able to use this code as it is. Converting to VB should be a simple syntax conversion.

Comment: Thank you. in C# it works. Although the recurrence isn't indefinite (because of the `DesiredCount`) it's a good start, maybe that's enough for me.
 I have to update my VB.net though, because my version doesn't support the VB yield statement yet.